# react-native android app quits before it launches (0.61.2) - couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so - Channel is unrecoverably broken

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to migrate from react-native 0.59.4 to 0.61.2.

After solving many many build and runtime problems on ios and android, this was the final problem before the successful launch of my react-native app on android. The app would build successfully but when it is time to launch on the emulator it would pop for a very brief moment then a white screen and application crashed with an *app keeps crashing* type of popup message. I can't even debug the app remotely on the chrome console since it doesn't launch in the first place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This solution worked for my specific problem. To find out your problem try `adb logcat *:E` to see what is wrong in your case.*

Ok, there is a very important command (I am on mac) that helps you see in the logs what is going on even if you can't launch the app on emulator: `adb logcat *:E`

In my case there were 2 main problems that caught my attention in the logs.

**Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed**

and

**couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so**

Once I got these messages on my radar I started to dig/google for them.

After going through a lot of SO and GitHub topics here is what worked for me:

First, make sure you have made all the necessary modifications in your:

- gradle.properties
- app/build.gradle
- android/build.gradle
- package.json
- etc

files (Use [react-native upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.4&to=0.61.2) to do this).

Then, if it is not installed already, do `npm install jsc-android` to install the required jsc package on your project.

Add the below in android/build.graddle inside *allprojects* -> *repositories*

```
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }
```

Inside gradle.properties add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In some cases you may need to add below line to package.json

```
"postinstall": "npx jetify"
```

Also, in some cases it may help to replace the below line (dependencies section of app/build.gradle) with the exact version of the react-native you are using:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

Replace like so:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:**0.61.2**"
```

I hope this helps to solve or at least make some progress with your problem.
Cheers.